# Execute link without clicking

Tags: php, sms-gateway

I am using an SMS gateway where the provider provides a link for their SMS gateway. If the link is clicked, an SMS will get delivered. My question is how can I execute it automatically? The link is the following:

```
http://www.smsjust.com/sms/user/urlsms.php?username=$sms_usernm&pass=$sms_pas&senderid=abc&dest_mobileno=$sms_mob&msgtype=TXT&message=$sms_msg&response=Y;
```

Comment: bind it off an event, prevent default, then make an XMLHttpRequest

Comment: submit your code for best answer

Comment: can you give example

Comment: In code there is only and anly a link as mentioned above

Comment: show your  html code and when you click in this link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$callurl = curl_init();

curl_setopt($callurl , CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.smsjust.com/sms/user/urlsms.php?username=$sms_usernm&pass=$sms_pas&senderid=abc&dest_mobileno=$sms_mob&msgtype=TXT&message=$sms_msg&response=Y;");
curl_setopt($callurl , CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($callurl );

curl_close($callurl );
```

Answer (score -2):

Don't know what you mean by "automatically" - if you want some client-side event to trigger the sending of your SMS - you can use JavaScript with an Ajax request - something like this:

```
function test()
{
obj={};
obj.username='john';
obj.pass='xx';
obj.senderid='xx';
obj.destmobileno='xx';
obj.smsmob='xx';
obj.message='xx';
obj.smsmsg='xx';

sendSMS(obj);
}


function sendSMS(obj)
{
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://www.smsjust.com/sms/user/urlsms.php',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: 
    {
        'username': obj.username,
        'pass': obj.pass,
        'senderid': obj.senderid,
        'dest_mobileno': obj.destmobileno,
        'sms_mob': obj.smsmob, 
        'message': obj.message,
        'sms_msg': obj.smsmsg,      
    },  
    dataType:'html',
    success: function(data) 
    { 
        console.log("success\n")
    },
     error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
         console.log("post failed\n");
     }});
  }
```

Comment: Oups ok, new to the forum sorry - I thought a Javascript alternative could have been useful :(